# Opening a URL with a "chrome" scheme through a desktop shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file

I want to create a shortcut that will direct me to chrome://bookmarks

Simply creating a desktop URL shortcut results in a problem with the shortcut, as it seems to only recognize the http scheme.

I've tried a simple batch command:

```
start chrome chrome://bookmarks
```

But this will open a new window without taking me to the URL.